# How do I make certain pages of my ruby on rails application inaccessible to one of my STI based Devise User model types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, sti

I want one pages of my ruby on rails web application inaccessible to one of my STI model types. I have two models typeA and typeB inheriting from User. I have used the column type in the User table to implement STI. I am using Devise gem for User sessions. I want one webpage 'http://localhost:3000/rate' inaccessible to my typeA User. Whenever an User logs in who is of the type 'typeA', he does not have the option of seeing the link 'Rate'. But I also do not want him to be able to access that page by the link 'http://localhost:3000/rate'. If he tries to access it through that link, I want to sign him out and make him log in again. 
I managed this by using a piece of code in my Controller with the specific method for 'rate'.

```
def rate
  if current_user.type == "typeA"
    sign_out(current_user)
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  else
    #Code for User of typeB
  end
end
```

This is working but I wanted to know if this can be done in a better way using **before_filter :authenticate_user!** or something else
Right now my before_filter part looks like this

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

Is there any way I can make a change to the upper code to achieve that functionality.
P.S: Maybe this can be done better if I had used roles or other gems like CanCan/Pundit but I do not have much time left to submit my project, so I do not want to get into all that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add another `before_filter` on the controller you want to restrict the access just to confirm your STI user type without overiding devise's `authenticate_user!` filter.

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def confirm_user_type(user_type)
    redirect_to new_user_session_path unless current_user.is_a?(user_type)
  end

end
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  # must be authenticated to access
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  # must be user of TypeA to access
  before_filter { |c| c.confirm_user_type(TypeA) }

  def rate
    ...
  end
end
```

Then, you can use the same filter `before_filter { |c| c.confirm_user_type(TypeB) }` for STI user `type: 'TypeB'`

Comment: I do not want the whole controller to be inaccessible to typeA. I want only the 'rate' page to be inaccessible to him. There are other methods like index, create, show etc, which should still be accessible to him. How do I put that in my code ?

Comment: you can use `only:` option to do that `before_filter { |c| c.confirm_user_type(TypeA) }, :only => [:rate]`

Comment: The error page that I get now is /Users/Suvajit/Documents/Code/Rails/Mckenzie/app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end .confirm_user_type(TypeA) } :only => [:rate] ^  
  
The code that I have used is 
   `before_filter  { |c| c.confirm_user_type(TypeA) }, :only => [:rate]`

Comment: try this: `before_filter { |c| c.action_name == "rate" && c.confirm_user_type(TypeA) }`

Comment: Hey this worked. I just also had to include the line `sign_out(current_user)`  before redirecting to new_user_session_path so that it doesn't say that the user is already signed in and redirects to the root page instead. Anyway, thanks a lot. I would have voted you your answer up but my stackoverflow reputation is below 15 so I can't make a vote.

Comment: You can accept the answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def authorize_user!
    if current_user.type == "typeA"
      sign_out(current_user)
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end

end
```

with your controller:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authorize_user!, except: [:index, :show]

    def top_secret
        ...
    end

end
```

I believe if a before_action (the new name for before_filter) renders or redirects, the action won't be processed.

Comment: This is not working. Now whenever I am trying to access even the pages that typeA is allowed to access, it is signing him out. Also when I am signed out and trying to access 'http://localhost:3000/rate', it shows a Rails error page stating that unknown variable 'current_user.type'. With the code that I had done earlier, when I am signed out and I would try to access 'http://localhost:3000/rate', it would just refresh the page with the Devise flash message stating 'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing' which I am good with. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ah didn't realise authenticate_user! was standard Devise, so you shouldn't be overriding it. I think the code here should work. It will first authenticate to set current_user, then authorize.